# Use sed to conditionally enclose string in quotes for all files in a directory

Tags: regex, sed, find

I have a directory containing several hundred weblog posting with YAML frontmatter. Each frontmatter block has a line beginning with `date:` followed by the date in YYYY-MM-DD format. Some of the dates are followed by the time, i.e., 21:09. A few of the dates are enclosed in single quotes, i.e., 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

I would like to convert all the `date:` lines to have this format: `date: 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Some sample date lines:

```
date: '2009-11-23'   
date: 2013-01-20 20:37
date: 2013-01-21 1:40
```

I have this command:

```
find . -type file -exec sed -i.bak -e "s/date: (')?([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2})(')?( .*)?/date: \"$2\"/g" {} \;
```

Which should create four groups:

- $1 the opening quote, if present
- $2 the date
- $3 the closing quote, if present
- $4 the time, if present

The command runs with no errors returned, but none of the date lines have changed. I used http://rubular.com to test the regex pattern, which appears to be correct.

For what it is worth I'm using macOS, and therefore its variants of `find` and `sed`. Since I am getting no output, other than a `.bak` file for each file in the directory, I can't tell if my regex is failing or if the substitution is failing.

How do I tweak this command to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` requires you to escape many special characters in a regexp, including `?(){}`. Also `sed` uses `\1` notation for replacements rather than `$1`. You can also simplify your regexp by removing the `date:` part as it is in both the search and replacement. This should work:

```
sed -e "s/'\?\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\).*$/\"\1\"/"
```